# I am creating a html file under a Django template, but on browser it shows the error file does not exists

Tags: django, python-3.x

i have facing these issue while creating template in `django`

```
as i am creating template while adding template attribute in setting.py its showing the error  syntax is invalid

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
            'APP_DIRS':True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 860, in get_code
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 791, in source_to_code
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "F:\myweb\myweb\settings.py", line 59
        'APP_DIRS': True,
                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

MPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [[os.path.join(BASE_DIR ,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS':True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myweb.wsgi.application'
```

i  am creating a html file under a django template but when i am trying to run it on browser it shows the error file doesnot exists

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class NewappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'newapp'
```

its have to show hello there!!!
on browser

Comment: `'DIRS': [[os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')]`. Look at the brackets.

Comment: The reason you see the error on the next line is that `, 'APP_DIRS'` would still be part of the array you're defining due to the double `[`, the `:` is the first character that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Closing bracket missing in `DIRS` value

```
'DIRS': [[os.path.join(BASE_DIR ,'templates')]],
```

`DIRS` expect a list so you can enter something like this also

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR ,'templates'),],
```

Credit to comment by @dirkgroten

Comment: Or just remove one square bracket